# No module named 'sqlalchemy.databases'

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

While trying to install the requirements to use magic sql, I encounter this error, No module named 'sqlalchemy.databases', with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine

# Presto
engine = create_engine('presto://localhost:8080/system/runtime') 

#Read Presto Data query into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_sql('select * from queries limit 1', engine)
df.head()
```

Thanks a lot for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

`ipython-sql` 0.5.0 depends on sqlalchemy 2 which deprecated the `sqlalchemy.databases` package in favor of the `sqlalchemy.dialects` package ([details](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/commit/ed78e679eafe787f4c152b78726bf1e1b91ab465)).

My solution was to pin both of these libraries to the following versions:

```
%pip install ipython-sql==0.4.1
%pip install sqlalchemy==1.4.46
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 on the answer above, it's a version mismatch issue I was experiencing as well!

So you can either lock both ipython-sql (0.4.9) and sqlalchemy (<2.0.0) versions or you can use a similar but different solution:

1. You can try using vanilla SQLAlchemy, without the magics and feeding the engine into your pandas data frame. It won't have magics with this solution and you'd have to run the SQL queries on the engine/via pandas which can cause memory issues (if using large datasets). This matches the code snippet you originally tried and posted here.
2. You can use [JupySQL](https://jupysql.ploomber.io/en/latest/quick-start.html) which is a fork of ipython-sql, that has support for SQLAlchemy v 2.0.0 and above. With that, you can enjoy both magics and avoid those out-of-memory issues pandas have when dealing with big data.